# Is a new function defined for every socket in Socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

The following is a code snippet from Socket.IO's website for the server code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {hello:'world'});
    socket.on('my other event', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

What I can tell from reading this code is that, upon connection, each socket independently defines its events. Although, since the same function is used to define these events, they're all the same. That is, every socket has `"my other event"`, which does the same thing, but each is a new instance of the function (wasteful).

My question is this: can/does V8 optimize this clearly wasteful practice? By, say, using the same function but within a different scope. Because the scope is different in each function, I would assume any function referencing `socket` has to be defined separately, effectively cloning this event for every single connection.

Is there an optimization I'm missing here, or is this just very bad practice? This also applies to any other instance of this practice, not just SIO; this is just the most prominent case.

Also, apologies if this was poorly conveyed, I can attempt to clarify if necessary.

Comment: The internals of JavaScript runtimes aren't the most public things, but it's probably safe to assume that because the *code* is constant, all that needs to be created for each socket event handler is a Function instance. All the instances can (one would think) use a shared copy of the code.

Comment: @Pointy I would hope because V8 is open source and this is the largest Q&A site for coding on the internet someone here would know. Also, I would love to know why this has -2 within 7 minutes of being asked. What, might I ask, is wrong with this question? This is a Q&A site, is it not?

Comment: YEs sorry, the word "public" was not the best choice. What I meant was that the subject is pretty arcane, and the number of people really (*really*) familiar with how it works is kind-of small. The way of writing code is *extremely* idiomatic in JavaScript, so it stands to reason that it would be a prime optimization concern. As to the downvotes, I can't explain; I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Pointy Unfortunately that small number leaves few places to go, so I figured SO's sheer size would offer the best chances of finding an answer. I was also hoping that since node is guaranteed to use V8 (not compiler-dependent) there would be a concrete answer specifically applying to it. I suppose I'll just have to take my curiosity to the front line and learn C, though. Thanks for being more friendly than some of the responses I get here.

Comment: Don't bother with some users of SO. Most of them just like "fix the code" questions. I don't know how v8 can optimize this, like @Pointy saied, few people really know v8 codes works. But sockets you usually open one ip:port and open the comunication. So you have one socket to manage all comunication with it, and scope optmizations has to be done after that. You will have the same for serial, usb, etc...

Comment: Instead of trying to reason through it from looking at the source code (what I interpreted as your 'learn C' comment), you could use various profiling tools for Node/V8, create a simulation to have 1,10,100,1000, etc websocket clients connect (or otherwise simulate the pattern) and see what the heap profile says about object creation and memory use. You can find some resources about V8's optimizations, particularly in [occasional talks](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=v8+compiler+google) and sometimes on [wingolog](http://wingolog.org/tags/v8) but I have found no great reference.

Answer (score 0):

This function can be rewritten as:

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', callback());

 function callback(socket) {
     socket.emit('news', {hello:'world'});
     socket.on('my other event', function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  }
```

My understanding of V8 is it monitors behaviors in the code and optimizes over time but that does not stop you from helping it along some. By writing the function like this you can do a bit of optimization to help V8 along. Most V8 optimization issues have to do with objects getting hidden typing, in this case yes I would think V8 does not see the function because it is inline and technically could be anything until the code is ran. If you are worried about it just dont write the code in `callback hell` style.